# Geometry and Footskip: Footer wrong placed

Tags: header-footer, geometry, footer, layout

I am writing simple LaTeX documents with just sections and text in between (in general), but I have some problems placing the footer correctly. My header comes from a template I have downloaded ages ago, but it had this problem for years.
Sometimes the text directly writes itself over the line of the footer. The footer should always be just a line and the page number under that. I am using these packages because of the header function, separated in three parts.
Example:
[image]

Here is an example code:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{geometry}
\setlength{\footskip}{0.2cm}
\usepackage[headsepline,footsepline]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\clearscrheadfoot
\ihead{Some Header Elements}
\chead{Middle}
\ohead{\today}
\cfoot{- \thepage \hspace{1pt} - }

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\blindtext
\section{Section 2}
\blindtext[30]

\end{document}
```

How are geometry and footskip working with each other, so how can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

footskip is the distance between the textbody and the *baseline* of the footer. 2mm is not enough here, use at least 6mm. You can set footskip in geometry, no need to do a \setlength.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=15mm,
           footskip=6mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[headsepline,footsepline]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\clearscrheadfoot
\ihead{Some Header Elements}
\chead{Middle}
\ohead{\today}
\cfoot{- \thepage \hspace{1pt} - }

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\blindtext
\section{Section 2}
\blindtext[30]

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Do you mean the line above the page number with baseline? I was a little bit confused about it and referred this to the bottom of the document first. Therefore I thought, that I need to calculate in between footskip and bottom. But it seems to work, thanks!

Comment: No the baseline of the footer is the line the "1" is sitting on.

Comment: I see. This makes sense now, because half of the one is bigger than 0.2cm. Thanks!

Comment: I added a picture for the distance, but it is exactly 6mm only if `\flushbottom` is active, with `\raggedbottom` the text can be shorter.

Comment: Just one more question to this: Is there any command which allows me to increase the distance between the line and the page number? So in the example, to move the - 1 - litt down. Is that also possible with one more command?

Comment: Thanks for adding that amazing explaining photo.

Answer (score 3):

it is easier to let `geometry` do all the setting, which can be done with `includefoot`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,usegeometry]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm,
   top=25mm,bottom=10mm,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[headsepline,footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ihead{Some Header Elements}
\chead{Middle}
\ohead{\today}
\cfoot{- \thepage \hspace{1pt} - }   
\begin{document}    
    \section{Section 1}
    \blindtext
    \section{Section 2}
    \blindtext[30]      
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want less space between text and footrule use `...,footskip=8mm]{geometry}`

Comment: Also thanks to you, this works fine as well.

Answer (score 2):

The absolute simplest solution is to let KOMA-script do the job. Since you are using 12pt font and A4 paper, `scrartcl` will automatically calculate a type area where the left, right and top margins are approximately 25mm, (exclusive header). The bottom margin will be ca. 31mm (to baseline of the page number).

Using KOMA-script internal functions gives you much better control, and the possibility to use all KOMA-script’s flexible commands without running into compatibility issues.

All you have to do is load `scrartcl` with the option `fontsize=12`, and KOMA-script will do the rest. In addition, you should use the new `scrlayer-scrpage` instead of `scrpage2`.

If you insist using `geometry` you should only load it once.

The package [widows-and-orphans](https://ctan.org/pkg/widows-and-orphans) is optional, but will help you to avoid widows and orphans (‘*enker og faderløse*’) in the document. And I changed the text to Norwegian to have correct hyphenation.

Here is the output and the code:

[image]

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}   % A4 is standard for KOMA-script
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}                  % Scalable fonts for microtype
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}    % For better linebreakes
\usepackage[headsepline=true, footsepline=true]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{widows-and-orphans}

\clearscrheadfoot
\ihead{Some Header Elements}
\chead{Middle}
\ohead{\today}
\cfoot{-- \thepage \hspace{1pt} -- }  % Alway use enspace

\begin{document}

\section{Fra representanten Audun Lysbakken}

[Teksten er hentet fra regjeringen.no, ]

Spørsmål: Kan statsråden gjøre rede den konkrete begrunnelsen for avgjørelsen om å stanse eksport av forsvarsmateriell og flerbruksvarer til Saudi-Arabia, hvorvidt denne avgjørelsen vil få konsekvenser for annen eksport til andre land, og hvor stort omfanget er på eksporten til Saudi-Arabia over allerede inngåtte lisenser? 

Begrunnelse: Utenriksdepartementet meldte fredag 9. november at det ikke lenger vil inngås lisenser til eksporten av forsvarsmateriell og flerbruksmateriell til Saudi-Arabia. I begrunnelsen vises det til at det er foretatt en helhetsvurdering, men det vises ikke til hvilke konkrete bestemmelser i regelverket som legges til grunn for avgjørelsen, eller om dette vil få konsekvenser for eksport til andre land. Spørsmålsstiller ønsker også at det redegjøres for i hvor stort omfang eksporten etter allerede inngåtte lisenser vil være.


\section{Utenriksministerens svar}
Norge har et meget strengt og omfattende eksportkontrollregelverk. Eksportkontrollforvaltningen følger Retningslinjer for Utenriksdepartementets behandling av søknader om eksport av forsvarsmateriell, samt teknologi og tjenester for militære formål av 28. februar 1992. Retningslinjene baserer seg blant annet på Stortingets vedtak av 11. mars 1959. Hovedprinsippet er at Norge ikke tillater eksport av forsvarsmateriell til områder hvor det er krig eller krig truer, eller til land der det er borgerkrig.

Ved en oppdatering 5. november 2014 ble kriteriene i EUs felles holdning om våpeneksport (2008/944/CSFP) artikkel 2 og de kriteriene som følger av ATTs artikler 6 og 7 innarbeidet i en konsolidert liste i retningslinjene. Retningslinjene gir også klare bestemmelser om krav til sluttbrukerdokumentasjon.

Når det gjelder Saudi-Arabia, står Norge i en annen situasjon enn mange andre land, fordi vi aldri har åpnet for eksport av våpen og ammunisjon (såkalt A-materiell) til landet. Utenriksdepartementet har besluttet at det i den nåværende situasjon heller ikke skal gis nye lisenser for eksport av annet forsvarsmateriell eller flerbruksvarer til militær bruk til Saudi-Arabia.

Beslutningen er fattet etter en helhetlig vurdering, og på grunnlag av et «føre-var» prinsipp. Den samme linjen ledet til at regjeringen i desember 2017 besluttet å suspendere eksport av A-materiell til De forente arabiske emirater (FAE), samt å ytterligere senke terskelen for å avslå eksport av annet militært materiell (B-materiell) til land som deltar i militære handlinger i Jemen.

At det må gjøres helhetlige og sammensatte vurderinger, følger av retningslinjene for eksport av forsvarsmateriell. Som nevnt ovenfor, reflekterer retningslinjene blant annet Stortingets 1959-vedtak, som forutsetter en grundig vurdering av de innen- og utenrikspolitiske forholdene i det aktuelle mottakerlandet.

Utenriksdepartementet gjør grundige, individuelle vurderinger av hver enkelt søknad om eksportlisens. Ved eksport av forsvarsmateriell kreves alltid dokumentasjon om sluttbruker før lisens kan innvilges. Dersom vi vurderer at det er en uakseptabel risiko for at det aktuelle utstyret kan bli brukt til intern undertrykking eller til å begå alvorlige brudd på humanitærretten eller menneskerettighetene, vil lisens ikke innvilges.

Omfanget av eksporten til Saudi-Arabia og andre land fremgår av de årlige meldingene til Stortinget. Gjennom disse meldingene ligger Norge i det internasjonale tetsjiktet når det gjelder åpenhet om eksporten av forsvarsmateriell. Samtidig må dette skje innenfor rammen av den lovpålagte taushetsplikten som følger av eksportkontrolloven.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Takk for svaret. Is the fact that widows-and-orphans package is imported already protecting from them or are there more commands to choose? I am already having the four lines \hbadness=10000
\clubpenalty = 10000
\widowpenalty = 10000
\displaywidowpenalty = 10000 in my document, I just removed them from the source code in the topic, because they weren't necessary.

Comment: The WaO set sensible values by design. You can use more aggressive values by give the option `prevent-all` or `avoid-all`. You should not use the value 10000 for `clubpenalty` and `widowpenalty`, because this may lead to really bad pagebreaks. It is then better with a widow or orphan or a page break before a display. The most important is to use [microtype](https://ctan.org/pkg/microtype).

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense and it's working in the document for me. But why isn't microtype used in your example above then? Or is it used implicit in some way?

Comment: By the way, thanks for including some Norwegian example. I am actually German, the norsk line was left from my last homework in language class. But it's always great to read some Norwegian texts here.

Comment: @DORpapst microtype was not used because the code shall be an MWE (minimal working example), and you also need to use another font (lmodern) to have scalable fonts. I have added two lines in the example.