# scrlayer-scrpage: distance between header/footer and continuous text

Tags: header-footer, vertical-spacing, scrlayer-scrpage

how could one increase / decrease the distance (vertical space) between the header / footer and the continuous text when using scrlayer-scrpage from koma script? Thx, Harald

I use the following entries:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,toc=listofnumbered,headinclude,footinclude,index=numbered,version=3.35]{scrbook}
\usepackage[papersize={155mm,232mm}, includeheadfoot, left=20mm, right=19mm, top=11mm, bottom=18mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ohead{\headmark}
\automark[section]{chapter}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\upshape\sffamily\small}
\setkomafont{pagefoot}{\sffamily\small}
```

Comment: The size of margins is not a feature of `scrlayer-scrpage` but of package `geometry`. See options `headsep` and `footskip` in [section 5.5 of the `geometry` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf#subsection.5.5).

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/136478 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503189 So it seems to be a kind of double duplicate.

Comment: Yes, thx. With the geometry package the distance between header and text can easily be edited.